# Develop on top of IronSpeed app without using IronSpeed?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ironspeed

I've been asked to do maintenance/development work on an ASP.NET app created with IronSpeed. Now here is the catch: 
a) the clients do not want me to use IronSpeed for further work, as their license is expiring and they do not want to renew;
b) the clients want me to maintain a consistent look-and-feel with the existing UI.

In principle, this should be possible. But the code looks very complex and unintuitive (no business classes, no data-access classes I could see, etc). I feel I may be walking into a minefield. Does anybody have any relevant experience with this kind of situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a little strange.  You would be forgoing a lot of the huge benefit in time savings and ease of maintenance if you were to just dump the code out of Iron Speed.  Plus, the cost of the software is quite modest.  You can subscribe for as little as $195 per month and cancel when you are not actively using the software.

The tool does generate an n-tier application.  You can learn more about the code model here:  http://www.ironspeed.com/Designer/9.1.0/WebHelp/Part_V/Code_Customization_Tutorial.htm#Code_Customization

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've had some experience doing this with IronSpeed versions 3.x and 5.x - but not with the current 9.x.

I found it difficult and laborious to maintain the app using Visual Studio, primarily because IronSpeed uses custom controls in a strange way. My recommendation would be not to do this, given that the subscription is relatively cheap. But it does depend on what version of IronSpeed was used to generate the original app. If it's an old version such as 3.x or 5.x, upgrading to 9.x can also be a major pain.